# how to make my code into a single parent/main class in apex and call the method of other sub class rather than writing many child classes in apex

Tags: apex

```java
public class GenRandNum {
    public Integer length = 2;
    public String randSequence = String.valueof(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()));
    public String randSlice = randSequence.substring(0, length);
    public String randomUniq (){
        return randSlice;
    }
}
```

```java
public class DateSequence {
    public String currentDate(){
        return String.valueOf(date.today()).replaceAll('-','');
    }
}
```

```java
public class DateArray {
    public List<String> getList(){
      DateSequence dati = new DateSequence();
      String dateValue = dati.currentDate();
        String [] arr = new List<String>();
        Integer chunkSize = 2;
           for(Integer i=0;i<dateValue.length();i+=chunkSize){
               String seq = dateValue.substring(i, i+chunkSize);
               arr.add(seq);              
           }
        arr.remove(0);
        return arr;
    }
}
```

```java
public class GenDateCode {
    public String genCode(List<String> seqList){
        String code = '';
        for(Integer i=0;i<seqList.size();i++){
            Integer num = Integer.valueOf(seqList[i]);
            if(i == 2){
code +=  seqList[i];               
            }
            else if(num >= 26){
                Integer times = Integer.valueOf(Math.floor(num/26));
                Integer cond = num  - 26 * times;
                code += String.fromCharArray( new List<integer> { 65+cond } );
                    } else {
                        code += String.fromCharArray( new List<integer> { 65+num-1} );
                    }
        }
        return code;
    }
}
```

```java
public class GenCode{
    public String getSequence(){
        DateArray dateArray = new DateArray();
        String [] li = dateArray.getList();
        GenDateCode gen = new GenDateCode();
        return gen.genCode(li);
    }
}
```

```java
public class AssembleCode{
    public String generate(){
        Gencode code = new GenCode();
        String seq = rand.randomUniq()+code.getSequence();
        return seq;
    }
}
```

```java
public class AutoIncrement{
    Public list<String>ai(){
        List<String>myarray = new list<String>();
        For(integer i=0;i<100;i++){
            string m = string.valueOf(i);
            if(i<10){
                (myarray.add('0'+m));
            }
            else{
                (myarray.add(m));
            }
            System.debug(myarray[i]);
        }
        return myarray;
    }
}
```

```java
    GenRandNum rand = new GenRandNum();   
    GenCode seq = new GenCode();
    AutoIncrement auto = new  AutoIncrement();
   System.debug(rand.randomUniq() + seq.getSequence() + auto.ai());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put them all into a top-level class:

```
public class Utils {
  public class GenRandNum {
    // ...
  }
  public class GenCode {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Which you then access through the top-level class:

```
Utils.GenRandNum rand = new Utils.GenRandNum();
Utils.GenCode seq = new Utils.GenCode();
Utils.AutoIncrement auto = new Utils.AutoIncrement();
```

However, note that you cannot place classes, static properties, or static methods inside these inner classes. If those classes refer to each other, you can place them all at the inner-class level of the top-level class. Also, you will need to refer to those classes by the top-level class name outside of the class, but not within the same top-level class.

This kind of design is a bit overkill, though; I'd suggest you simply have a set of static methods all in a single top-level class (e.g. `Utils`), unless you plan on having more than 20 or so methods, in which case I'd break them out into more refined classes, such as `DateUtils` and `Generators`, or something like that, whatever you feel makes the most sense for your code.

Comment: @user125850 Please edit your question to include all the new code you wrote, and I'll be happy to take a look at it with you. The error, in general, means that you are trying to call a method incorrectly.